# Finding The First Non-repeating Character algorithm Swift 4 (Looping over string only once)

Tags: swift, string, algorithm

I am trying to solve code fights interview practice questions, but I am stuck on how to solve this particular problem in swift. My first thought was to use a dictionary with the counts of each character, but then I would have to iterate over the string again to compare, so that doesn't work per the restrictions. Any help would be good. Thank you. Here is the problem and requirements:

Note: Write a solution that only iterates over the string once and uses O(1) additional memory, since this is what you would be asked to do during a real interview.

Given a string s, find and return the first instance of a non-repeating character in it. If there is no such character, return '_'

Here is the code I started with (borrowed from another post)

```
func firstNotRepeatingCharacter(s: String) -> Character {

var countHash:[Character:Int] = [:]


    for character in s {
        countHash[character] = (countHash[character] ?? 0) + 1
    }


let nonRepeatingCharacters = s.filter({countHash[$0] == 1})

    let firstNonRepeatingCharacter = nonRepeatingCharacters.first!

return firstNonRepeatingCharacter

}

firstNotRepeatingCharacter(s:"abacabad")
```

Comment: It would help to quote the exact problem statement. – Does "a" in "bacad" count as repeating character? Or is it about consecutive repeating characters, such as "a" in "baad"?

Comment: can you give a link to the challenge?

Comment: @thebenman https://codefights.com/interview-practice/task/uX5iLwhc6L5ckSyNC/description

Comment: @MartinR "abacabad" was just a test case I used. They have multiple test cases.

Comment: You did not answer my question. – Please add the precise problem statement to your question.

Comment: @MartinR I did... this is the exact problem statement: Note: Write a solution that only iterates over the string once and uses O(1) additional memory, since this is what you would be asked to do during a real interview.

Given a string s, find and return the first instance of a non-repeating character in it. If there is no such character, return '_'

Comment: Again: Does "nonrepeating"  mean "different from the previous character" or  "different from all  other characters"?

Comment: @MartinR I see what you are getting at now. It is asking if a character is different from all other characters.

Comment: One of the first Google hits for your problem is http://www.brunocalendreau.com/2017/07/05/interview-practice-firstnotrepeatingcharacter/, and that shows a possible approach.

Comment: @MartinR I saw that, but didn't get it to work, though after solving it  with leo's help I was able to view other solutions. If I had copied the string into an array I could have done it the way that is shown there, but for some reason that had not occurred to me.

Comment: You can't have this in `O(1)` for both time and space. You have to sacrifice one of them, you need to decide which.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a dictionary to store the occurrences and use first(where:) method to return the first occurrence that happens only once:

**Swift 4**

```
func firstNotRepeatingCharacter(s: String) -> Character {
    var occurrences: [Character: Int] = [:]
    s.forEach{ occurrences[$0, default: 0] += 1 }
    return s.first{ occurrences[$0] == 1 } ?? "_"
}
```

**Swift 3**

```
func firstNotRepeatingCharacter(s: String) -> Character {
    var occurrences: [Character:Int] = [:]
    s.characters.forEach{ occurrences[$0] = (occurrences[$0] ?? 0) + 1}
    return s.characters.first{ occurrences[$0] == 1 } ?? "_"
}
```

Another option iterating the string in reversed order and using an array of 26 elements to store the characters occurrences

```
func firstNotRepeatingCharacter(s: String) -> Character {
    var chars = Array(repeating: 0, count: 26)
    var characters: [Character] = []
    var charIndex = 0
    var strIndex = 0
    s.characters.reversed().forEach {
        let index = Int(String($0).unicodeScalars.first!.value) - 97
        chars[index] += 1
        if chars[index] == 1 && strIndex >= charIndex {
            characters.append($0)
            charIndex = strIndex
        }
        strIndex += 1
    }
    return characters.reversed().first { chars[Int(String($0).unicodeScalars.first!.value) - 97] == 1 } ?? "_"
}
```

Comment: thank you.  I was not aware of first(where:). That's what held me up with the dictionary approach I was using. I knew to use a hash table but was unaware of that function.

Comment: The dictionary seems like constant memory since it only has as many keys as there are possible characters (e.g. only has 26 keys if the string is lowercase alphabetic, regardless of string length). But `first` seems like looping twice

Comment: @Philip it will depend where is the first occurrence. it can be the first character or the last. filter would iterate all characters in all cases

Comment: I'd iterate the dictionary rather than the string... That is guaranteed to be constant

Comment: @Philip a dictionary is an unordered collection.

Comment: I'll agree that the dictionary *is* O(1) since the number of keys is limited. But you are still iterating more than once. – This looks helpful: http://www.brunocalendreau.com/2017/07/05/interview-practice-firstnotrepeatingcharacter/.

Comment: Yep, you'd need to use an ordered dict (not sure about swift but pythons got em). Alternatively, store the index that the character was first encountered at with the count.

Comment: Fails for `"aabbc"` :(

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary to store the character counts as well as where they were first encountered. Then, loop over the dictionary (which is constant in size since there are only so many unique characters in the input string, thus also takes constant time to iterate) and find the earliest occurring character with a count of 1.

```
func firstUniqueCharacter(in s: String) -> Character 
{
    var characters = [Character: (count: Int, firstIndex: Int)]()

    for (i, c) in s.characters.enumerated()
    {
        if let t = characters[c]
        {
            characters[c] = (t.count + 1, t.firstIndex)
        }
        else
        {
            characters[c] = (1, i)
        }
    }

    var firstUnique = (character: Character("_"), index: Int.max)
    for (k, v) in characters
    {
        if v.count == 1 && v.firstIndex <= firstUnique.index
        {
            firstUnique = (k, v.firstIndex)
        }
    }

    return firstUnique.character
}
```

Comment: You should return a character not a string

Comment: `var firstUnique = (character: Character("_"), index: Int.max)`

Comment: and `firstUnique = (k, v.firstIndex)` and change the return type to `Character`

Comment: Yeah you're right, if that signature is important. Changed accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift**

Use dictionary, uniqueCharacter optional variable with unique characters array to store all uniquely present characters in the string , every time duplication of characters found should delete that character from unique characters array and same time it is the most first character then should update the dictionary with its count incremented , refer following snippet , how end of the iteration through all characters gives a FIRST NON REPEATED CHARACTER  in given String. Refer following code to understand it properly

```
func findFirstNonRepeatingCharacter(string:String) -> Character?{
    var uniqueChars:[Character] = []
    var uniqueChar:Character?
    var chars = string.lowercased().characters
    var charWithCount:[Character:Int] = [:]
    for char in chars{
        if let count = charWithCount[char] {   //amazon
            charWithCount[char] = count+1
            if char == uniqueChar{
                uniqueChars.removeFirst()
                uniqueChar = uniqueChars.first
            }
        }else{
            charWithCount[char] = 1
            uniqueChars.append(char)
            if uniqueChar == nil{
                uniqueChar = char
            }
        }
    }
    return uniqueChar
}
// Use
findFirstNonRepeatingCharacter(string: "eabcdee")
```